# OpenCV image copied is different from original

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to copy one image to another by slicing ***numpy*** array, but i am getting complete black output in ***imshow***, if using `dtype=int` otherwise it's something different as shown in the image below. While the pixel values are same in both the images. Here is the sample code:

```
import sys

import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    img = cv2.imread('ele.jpg', 1)
    h, w, c = img.shape
    img_copy = np.empty((h, w, c), dtype=int)
    img_copy[0:h, 0:w] = img
    print (img[50:54, 50:54])
    print (img_copy[50:54, 50:54].shape)
    cv2.imshow('ele', img)
    cv2.imshow('ele-copy', img_copy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong data type. Changing the data type of `img_copy` to `np.uint8` should fix your issue.

```py
img_copy = np.empty((h, w, c), dtype=np.uint8)
```

However, I would simply use:

```py
img_copy = img.copy()
```